# How could a reverse SSH tunnel be instantiated remotely via the web?

Tags: ssh, nat, reverse-tunnel

I have a remote server behind a firewall and a NAT with no external IP address. I want to be able to establish a reverse SSH connection with this server. The issue is getting the remote server to instantiate the reverse SSH connection to my local computer at my command.

Assuming I have superuser privileges on the remote server and that the remote server in its default state has only basic web access, how could I communicate sensibly with the server in order to get it to instantiate a reverse SSH connection?

As an extremely coarse solution, imagine my creating a webpage which is monitored continuously by the remote server and that the webpage is changed in some way to communicate to the remote server to instantiate a reverse SSH connection.

What would be a more sensible approach? Could communications be established via a decentralised system, like BitTorrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get out the bailing wire and duct tape, but this is what I've done in the past

1. On some web server out there, put a file.
2. On the server you want to start the connection, have it wget that file in a script run by cron every X minutes or at certain times of day
3. If the file is not there (or if it is... up to you) then start a screen session sshing out to whatever host and authenticating and establishing your tunnel